# Coding for TI CC2650

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy

JavaScript question:
I appreciate any help anyone could give me with this. I have the TI CC2650 SENSOR. What I wanted to accomplish is in JavaScript?

SCENARIO 1

- So l setup a height value.
- The sensor is on the floor. Every time I pick the sensor and lift it to that height, the phone will do something(vibrate, play a small song, etc)

SCENARIO 2

- The phone is on the top of the table;
- The sensor is on the floor;
- I pick up the sensor and the phone will tell me how far the sensor is the closer it gets;

Which sensor(s) do I use to accomplish that?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify: I don't care for exact numbers. I don't need exact distances. I just need to set a number that I can code a trigger response from the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not about the following:

- Javascript
- TI CC2650

Your question is about the following:

- Altitude Sensor

Let me answer your question though:

[SparkFun Altitude/Pressure Sensor Breakout - MPL3115A2](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11084)

This has 30 cm resolution. 30 cm resolution means that there is no difference between standing on the ground or being lifted to 29 cms .

[BMP180 Barometric Pressure/Temperature/Altitude Sensor- 5V ready](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1603)

This dude has 25 cm resolution, so it might be slightly more useful.

NOTE: They both work at 3.3V Vcc, which means you can feed the sensor from the same source as your TI CC2650. If you don't know what Vcc is, you should do more reading.

You might also find more useful options for yourself if you do some more googling about altitude sensors, altimeters and relevant stuff.